# Comparing INT and NVARCHAR

Tags: t-sql

T-SQL newbie here. I am sure you guys can help me with a little problem I'm having.

Here's my situation:

I want to do a select from a certain table. And with that select I want to display the count of a referenced entry in another table.

So here's my script:

```
/****** Skript für SelectTopNRows-Befehl aus SSMS ******/
SELECT [ID]
  ,[ExpenseNumber]
  ,[Mandator]
  -- some more rows here

  -- Memo
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [Foobar].[dbo].[MemoUnion]
    WHERE ([Mandator] = 096)
    AND ([ReferenceType] = 4001)
    AND ([Reference] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = [ID])) AS [MemoCount]
    FROM [Foobar].[dbo].[Expense]
    WHERE Mandator = 096 AND ExpenseNumber = 1;
```

So here's my problem, the column `[MemoCount]` shows 0, although I am 100% sure that there is an actual entry in `dbo.MemoUnion` where `Reference = ID` is actually true.

My suspicion is that it's not working because `[Reference]` is `nvarchar` and `[ID]` is an `int`.

So I fiddled around with `CONVERT()` and `CAST()`. But the result stays 0 none the less.

I did not get any error messages while using `CONVERT` and/or `CAST`. Just always a result of 0.

Any tips?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What datatype is Mandator? I don't believe Mandator can ever = 096, it would have to be '096' or 96. You cannot have a leading 0 on an int.

Comment: it's a char(3). The two constraints [Mandator] = 096 and [ReferenceType] = 4001 work perfectly fine. I can test that by just select * from dbo.foobar.memounion where [Mandator] = 096 AND ReferenceType = 4001. That works perfectly fine and shows the correct row.

Comment: So to me the problem has to be the [ReferenceType] = [ID] part. But I could be wrong of course.

Comment: Ok, well if it's a char, it should really be wrapped in ''. I assume you've tried (AND [Reference] = CAST([ID] AS NVARCHAR(10)))?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it myself.
In case someone runs into a similar problem:
[dbo].[MemoCount] also has an ID Column.
so i changed

```
AND ([Reference] COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS = [ID]))
```

to:

```
AND ([Reference]  = [Foobar].[dbo].[Expense].[ID])) AS [MemoCount]
```

Apparently SQL took the column [dbo].[MemoUnion].[ID] to compare it with [Reference].
That problem was of course not solvable for you guys because I never posted the Columns of [dbo].[MemoUnion] in the first place.
Thanks for all the suggestions nonetheless!